# How does sklearn calculates the area under the roc curve for a binary classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This might appear as a duplication of another question which has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881615/how-does-sklearn-calculate-the-area-under-the-roc-curve-for-two-binary-inputs). However, I've looked at the answer there and still cannot understand how Scikit-learn calculates the area under the roc curve by testing only one threshold, which is the one provided in the:

`y_pred = clf.predict(X_test) 
roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)`

why it doesn't take multiple values (multiple y_test, y_pred that results from multiple thresholds)?any simplified explanation would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for `roc_auc_score()` in this case should be the
prediction probability obtained by `clf.predict_proba(X_test)`.
The different thresholds are calculated inside this function on the 
basis of this prediction probabilities. 
There is an example for this in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
0.75
```

To understand how the `roc_auc_score` is caluclated it might be helpful
to look at the `roc_curve` it self. This can be done with the function
`sklearn.metrics.roc_curve()`. Example taken from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, scores, pos_label=2)
fpr
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ])
tpr
array([ 0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ])
thresholds
array([ 0.8 ,  0.4 ,  0.35,  0.1 ])
```

(Eventhough the `y` is different in the latter example it is still a binary
classification with 2 being the positive class.)

As can be seen in the latter example the different thresholds are taken
from the supplied `scores`.

The [ROC Curve](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_Operating_Characteristic) would be generated by putting the True Positive Rate `tpr` on the y-axis and the False Positive Rate `fpr` on the x-axis of a plot.

Comment: what if I have used `y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)`  instead of the `clf.predict_proba(X_test)` .. according to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159157/different-result-with-roc-auc-score-and-auc) I think it still possible

Comment: You are right in that it is possible to use the `clf.predict` output, but this has some implications and may not calculate the desired quantity. Given a binary classification `clt.predict` returns an array containing zeros or ones. These values can also be interpreted as scores (which range normally from 0 to 1). The difference to the scores returned by `clf.predict_proba`

Comment: ... (which are not only 0 or 1) is that you only have the two possible thresholds. 1) Everything with a score above ore equal to one is assumed to be the positive class. 2) Everything with a score above or equal to 0 is taken.

Comment: I checked it on a example using random numbers for `y_true`, `y_prediction` and `y_score`. Using the `roc_curve(y_true, y_prediction)` gives you 3 thresholds. The two above (0 and 1) and a third one at 2, which I have to admit I do not understand as of now.