# Calculate threshold for roc_curve for binary classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, roc, auc

The question is similar to the one mentioned in the link below, please read it for reference.

[How does sklearn calculate the area under the roc curve for two binary inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881615/how-does-sklearn-calculate-the-area-under-the-roc-curve-for-two-binary-inputs/60629628#60629628)

I understand that everything is happening in `sklearn.metrics._binary_clf_curve`.

But for binary classification, how are multiple thresholds being calculated/decided in the said function. The function returns `y_score[threshold_idxs]` as thresholds to plot roc_curve, I am unable to understand the calculation of `y_score[threshold_idxs]` and why will this be threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use the [scikit-learn 0.22.2 documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) as a compass to understand each component of the function and the final result.

- **function**:

```py
sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=None, sample_weight=None, drop_intermediate=True)
```

- "active" **parameters** if using the default call:

  - `y_true`: array, shape = [n_samples], True binary labels.
  - `y_score`: array, shape = [n_samples]. Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions
  - `drop_intermediate`: boolean, optional (default=True), Whether to drop some suboptimal thresholds which would not appear on a plotted ROC curve.
- **outputs**:

  - `fpr`: array, shape = [>2], Increasing false positive rates such that element i is the false positive rate of predictions with score >= thresholds[i].
  - `tpr`: array, shape = [>2], Increasing true positive rates such that element i is the true positive rate of predictions with score >= thresholds[i].
  - `thresholds`: array, shape = [n_thresholds], Decreasing thresholds on the decision function used to compute fpr and tpr

Now, considering the code for [`roc_curve()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L686), it calls the function [`_binary_clf_curve()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L498), where after proper manipulations and sorting, it computes:

```
distinct_value_indices = np.where(np.diff(y_score))[0]
threshold_idxs = np.r_[distinct_value_indices, y_true.size - 1]
```

The explanation of these lines is in the comment:

> `y_score` typically has many tied values. Here we extract the indices associated with the distinct values. We also concatenate a value for the end of the curve.

**The two lines above roughly answer** to your question *how are multiple thresholds being calculated/decided*.

Then, it computes:

```
tps = stable_cumsum(y_true * weight)[threshold_idxs]
fps = 1 + threshold_idxs - tps
```

and returns:

```
return fps, tps, y_score[threshold_idxs]
```

After that, returning on the main function `roc_curve()`, if [`if drop_intermediate and len(fps) > 2:`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L782), it

> attemps to drop thresholds corresponding to points in between and
>   collinear with other points.

```
optimal_idxs = np.where(np.r_[True,
                              np.logical_or(np.diff(fps, 2),
                                            np.diff(tps, 2)),
                              True])[0]
```

and the "new" values are:

```
fps = fps[optimal_idxs]
tps = tps[optimal_idxs]
thresholds = thresholds[optimal_idxs]
```

after that you can see other manipulations, but the core is what I have highlighted above.

Comment: So if there are thresholds corresponding to points not in between and collinear with other points, they won't be dropped?
Also the no. of values that are unique in y_score will go on to become the no. of thresholds before being dropped?

Comment: Note that the default setting is `drop_intermediate=True`. You can change it to `drop_intermediate=False` to preserve suboptimal thresholds.